# l2tp/IPsec vpn: Cannot diable PFS

Tags: vpn, 21.04, ipsec, framerate, l2tp

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 and I wanted to connect to a VPN. I have installed the `network-manager network-manager-l2tp network-manager-gnome`. I have another laptop using Fedora and installed the same packages and I could disable FPS, however I cannot disable FPS in Ubuntu. I have tried connecting to my school's vpn without disabling VPN but it did not work. If anyone have any idea how to do it please comment :)

P.S. I am just moving to Linux and I am not totally familiar with the CLI, so please give me more detailed instructions if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

network-manager-l2tp auto-detects which IPsec daemon you are using, by default on Ubuntu it is strongswan, while on Fedora it is libreswan. The differences on the default IPsec daemon are because of historical reasons.

Read about PFS parameter for strongswan on the following page :

- https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/connsection

Basically the PFS parameter hasn't been used since strongswan 5.0.0 was released 8 years ago. Consequently the PFS checkbox is grayed out.

If you want to replace strongswan with libreswan on Ubuntu, issue:

```
sudo apt install librewan
```